# Change UIBezierArc colour, when its handle is drawn inside or outside from handle only

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I have a circular slider, which has a bezier arc drawn in it, an arc has two handles at start and end point in slider, arc is drawn in  circular slider.

I am able to draw bezier curve along the circular slider with the help of start and end handles.

I want to change the colour of arc when it is dragged 45 inside or 45 outside from handle only and it should not change arc colour when it is dragged in the circular slider.

**Note- while dragging inside and outside it should not change other slider arc's color.**

The color should only change, when it is dragged inside and outside only not when it is dragged in circle.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
_dragging = YES;

if (!self.isDragging)
{
    return;
}

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sliderDraggin:)])
{
    [self.delegate sliderDraggin:self];
}

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
//UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

NSUInteger nearestHandleIndex = [self indexOfNearesPointForTouch:touch];
_nearesHandle = (nearestHandleIndex != NSNotFound) ? _handles[@(nearestHandleIndex)] : nil;


CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
CGFloat distance = [_math distanceBetweenPoint:_centerPoint andPoint:location];



CGFloat inOff = _radius - _sliderWidth - _offset.inside;
CGFloat outOff = _radius + _offset.outside;

if (distance < inOff || distance > outOff)
{
    if (self.isNeedToRevoke)
    {
        _dragging = NO;
        return;
    }
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    int a = AngleFromNorth(_centerPoint, location, EVA_FLIPPED);
    [self moveView:_nearesHandle toAngle:a];

    [self drawArc];
});

[self informDelegateAboutHandles];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've calculated the `distance`.

1. So, first, don't exit if it's less than `< inOff` or `> outOff`.
2. Instead, set the color based upon `distance`, perhaps:

   ```
   UIColor *arcColor;

   if (distance < (inOff - 45)) { 
       arcColor = [UIColor redColor];
   } else if (distance > (outOff + 45)) { 
       arcColor = [UIColor redColor];
   } else { 
       arcColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   }
   ```

   Clearly, tweak the logic as you see fit, but that's likely to be the basic idea.
3. Use this `arcColor` to update whatever color-specific property is used by your drawing routine.

---

I don't have enough to figure out how you rendered these arcs, but [this repo](https://github.com/robertmryan/ColoredArcs) contains sample app that updates `strokeColor` of `CAShapeLayer` for the individual arcs based upon the touches, yielding the following:

[image]

I wouldn't worry too much about reconciling my implementation with yours, but it just illustrates the pattern shown above, where you calculate which arc to update in `touchesBegan` and update the color in `touchesMoved`.

Comment: in this case when i press handle and drag inside or outside  the slider it take some extra width i change 45 to 5 so when i drag a long inside and long outside the colors are chnaging. if i need to do anything just in and off the slider width.

Comment: i want to modify the colour value as soon as dragged handle leave the slider  - inside our outside and then i am updating to another color to 45 inside and outside. please suggest me

Comment: if I try to drag 1 handler inside and when it comes near to second slider in that case both slider arc 1 and slider 2 both gets same color .Is it possible to restrict change only selected arc handler color. Please do update me

Comment: could you please help me out on this

Comment: Based upon your original description, I inferred that you wanted to change the color of the whole arc based upon the distance from the center of the arc (which is what I thought was what your black arrows indicated). I apologies, but simply I'm not understanding any of your comments here. At this point, I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea of what you're trying to achieve. Maybe edit your question to include some snapshots (even if hand drawn) showing what you want it to look at various points of the gesture (perhaps with some visual cue as to where the user's finger is at that point).

Comment: I tried and it works but when I drag inside or outside near to any other arc it does change their color and other arcs are effected. I need to change only color of selected arc handler. Please do update me

Comment: i have one condition 90 distance inside and outside.

Comment: if I want to delete arc from supervise once it is between 45 to 90 in both cases inside and outside it does not work and it removes all arcs from circle . I have checked it it is not working rob . Please do check

Comment: could you update your answer based on updated question

Comment: could you please suggest me what is the correct condition I need to frame

Comment: @ChenSmile - I don't understand your comment ("condition I need to frame"?). But I've [uploaded a demonstration](https://github.com/robertmryan/ColoredArcs) of what I was talking about. Now, my implementation is completely different than yours and you might even have different desired UX, so don't get lost in the weeds there, but it illustrates the idea of updating an arc on screen on the basis of touches on the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot rob really you helped us developer in need. I really want to know what is master to learn any programming language you are expert in objective and swift. How to master could you please tell on that